# How to avoid the "How was your experience?" feedback screen on Zoom meeting?

Tags: zoom-meeting

At end of every Zoom meeting I received the following feedback screen.

Is there any settings to avoid the feedback screen for every meeting?

---

[image: Feedback]

---

> How was your experience?
> Great
> Had Issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen above is normally under the control of your Zoom Administrator. They may want this feedback to improve meetings. This is the main reason for this screen. You need to ask your meeting host.

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/214193146-End-of-Meeting-Attendee-Feedback

It is possible (but less likely) that your Zoom client has this setting. I have not seen any of our Zoom client with this setting enabled.

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115005855266

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case "Feedback to Zoom" was "Locked by admin". But atleast I know there is an option to disable.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: The option is enabled for Zoom client now. Reference: https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115005855266#h_78929c1c-ce09-47ce-a1dc-98e5c38d90e5

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your **Settings**
2. Click the **Meeting** tab at the top of the page (to the left of General)
3. Select **In Meeting (Basic)** in the left sidebar
4. Scroll down to **Display end-of-meeting experience feedback survey**
5. **Uncheck** the toggle button
6. Restart the Zoom app (quit and reopen)

[image: Settings]